# Undefined function 'F' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: loops, matlab, numerical-methods, convolution, numerical-integration

I am trying to create a function F(t) that is equal to a convolution integral, and then compute theta_n(n+1) by taking the value F(tn). However, I'm getting the error "Undefined function 'F' for input arguments of type 'char'". What's the problem?

```
function [ theta ] = Untitled( theta_o,omega_o )
nt=5001; %since (50-0)/.01 = 5000
dt = .01; % =H
H=.01;

theta_n = ones(nt,1);
theta_n(1)=0; %theta_o
omega_n = ones(nt,1);
omega_n(1)=-0.4; %omega_o
epsilon=10^(-6);
eta = epsilon*10;
t_o=0;

for n=1:4999
    tn=t_o+n*dt;
    F := int((422.11/eta)*exp((5*(4*((eta*t-s-tn)^2)/eta^2)-1)^(-1))*omega, s,tn-    (n/2),tn+(n/2))
    theta_n(n+1) = theta_n(n) + h*F(tn);
end

end
```

Comment: `:=` is no valid matlab syntax. Don't know what you intended to implement.

Comment: Were you looking at the version of [`int` on this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/int.html)? Read the notice at the top of that page. You're looking for the documentation for [`sym/int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) in the symbolic toolbox, which is effectively the same, but works directly within Matlab. However, I'm not sure `sym/int` will return a `symfun` like you seem to expect.

Comment: I'm trying to write a loop that calculates the value of a definite integral at each step. The function F is very complicated. To put it in simple terms, it integrates a bunch of terms with respect to s, from s=tn-(n/2) to s=tn+(n/2). After the integration, F still has a variable t. So you can say F(t) = integral(f(s,t)), where f(s,t) is the big mess of terms after "int(". In the last line of the for loop, I want to evaluate F(t) at t=tn after F computes the integral of f(s,t)

Answer (score 0):

What about `F = @(tn) ...;`?

Probably you mixed up some other things in this code as well, e.g. `H` vs. `h` and so on...